# How to get features names from a count matrix?

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, centroid

I need to know the features from a count matrix. I already have tokenized data and I have the term-document-matrix and I don't need to do Tfidfvectorizer. I tired to do like this example:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer

but I found this is for raw documents. I got this error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'

this is my try:

```
pipe = make_pipeline(TruncatedSVD(n_components=svd_components),
       Normalizer(norm='l1',copy=False))

transformed = pipe.fit_transform(term_documt_matrix)

km = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters,init='random', n_init=10,
max_iter=100, verbose=0)

clusters = km.fit_predict(transformed)

order_centroids = km.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]

terms = transformed.get_feature_names()

for i in range(n_clusters):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i, end='')
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind], end='')
    print()
```

Any help please?

Comment: How does the code know about the feature names? Is `term_documt_matrix` a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @maxymoo It is coo_matrix. I have the original data with 4 columns term_id document_id and term_count and term_name